# JW Player - Amazon Web Services CDN and Advanced Javascript Debugging

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront, jwplayer7

I have a customized JW Player 7 Pro embedded on the following page: http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/jw-player-self-hosted/.

The embed code is as follows:

```html
<!--Course Video, Scripts and Style-->
<div id="visualSPPlayer">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var playerInstance = jwplayer("visualSPPlayer");
  playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/Search2013.mp4",
    primary: "HTML5",
    image: "https://assets-jpcust.jwpsrv.com/thumbs/2kOAeo0k-320.jpg?1443200073230",
    width: "100%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    tracks: [
      {
        file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/captions/Search/Captions.srt",
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions",
      },
      {
        file: 'http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/chapters/Search/Chapters.vtt',
        kind: 'chapters'
  
      },
      {
        file: "http://dbt8c2ssdzlxg.cloudfront.net/thumbnails/search_thumbnails.vtt",
        kind: "thumbnails"
      }
    ],
    skin: {
      name: "vapor",
      active: "#E16933",
      inactive: "#E16933",
      background: "#333333"
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/wp-content/themes/symplex-child/js/player.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/wp-content/themes/symplex-child/css/player.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

The player.js file contents:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery(function ($) {

    var playerInstance = jwplayer();
    var chapters = [];
    var captions = [];
    var toc = [];
    var caption = -1;
    var matches = [];
    var seekArr = [];
    var seekPos = [];
    var seePos;
    var query = "";
    var cycle = -1;

    var transcript = document.getElementById('courseTranscript');
    var search = document.getElementById('courseSearch');
    var match = document.getElementById('courseMatch');

    var caption_file;
    var chapter_file;

    playerInstance.onReady(function () {
      //Self-Hosted
      caption_file = playerInstance.getPlaylist()[0].tracks[0].file;
      chapter_file = playerInstance.getPlaylist()[0].tracks[1].file;

      if (playerInstance.getRenderingMode() == "flash") {
        return;
      }

      tag = document.querySelector('video');
      tag.defaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
      tag.playbackRate = 1.0;

      playerInstance.addButton("http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/hare.png", "1.5x", function () {
        playerInstance.seek(playerInstance.getPosition());
        tag.playbackRate = 1.5;
      }, "playerHighSpeed");

      playerInstance.addButton("http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/normal.png", "1.0x", function () {
        playerInstance.seek(playerInstance.getPosition());
        tag.playbackRate = 1.0;
      }, "playerNormalSpeed");

      playerInstance.addButton("http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/snail.png", "0.5x", function () {
        playerInstance.seek(playerInstance.getPosition());
        tag.playbackRate = 0.5;
      }, "playerSlowSpeed");
    });

    //Adds Player Focus on Playing
    playerInstance.on('play', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".jwplayer").offset().top - 190
      }, 1000);
    });

    playerInstance.onReady(function () {
      $.get(caption_file, function (data) {
        data = data.trim();
        var t = data.split("\n\r\n");

        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
          var c = parse(t[i]);
          chapters.push(c);
        }
        loadCaptions();
        loadChapters();
      });
      //
    });

    // Load chapters / captions
    function loadCaptions() {
      $.get(caption_file, function (data) {
        data = data.trim();
        var t = data.split("\n\r\n");
        t.pop();
        var h = "<p>";
        var s = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
          var c = parse(t[i]);
          
          if (s < chapters.length && c.begin > chapters[s].begin) {
            s++;
          }
          
          h += "<span id='caption" + i + "'>" + c.text + "</span>";
          captions.push(c);
        }
        transcript.innerHTML = h + "</p>";
      });
    };

    function parse(d) {
      var a = d.split("\n");
      //console.log(a[1]);
      var i = a[1].indexOf(' --> ');
      var t = a[2]; //Caption text

      if (a[3]) {
        t += " " + a[3];
      }
      
      t = t.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
      
      return {
        begin: seconds(a[1].substr(0, i)),
        btext: a[1].substr(3, i - 7),
        end: seconds(a[1].substr(i + 5)),
        text: t
      }
    };

    function seconds(s) {
      var a = s.split(':');
      secs = a[2].substring(0, a[2].indexOf(','));
      var r = Number(secs) + Number(a[a.length - 2]) * 60;

      if (a.length > 2) {
        r += Number(a[a.length - 3]) * 3600;
      }
      
      return r;
    };

    function toc_seconds(s) {
      var a = s.split(':');
      secs = a[2].substring(0, a[2].indexOf('.'));
      var r = Number(secs) + Number(a[a.length - 2]) * 60;
      
      if (a.length > 2) {
        r += Number(a[a.length - 3]) * 3600;
      }
      
      return r;
    };

    function toc_time(s) {
      var a = s.split(':');
      var ms = a[2].split(".");
      var h = a[0];

      if (h != "00") {
        var r = a[0] + ":" + a[1] + ":" + ms[0];
      } else {
        var r = a[1] + ":" + ms[0];
      }

      return r;
    };

    // Highlight current caption and chapter
    playerInstance.onTime(function (e) {
      var p = e.position;
      for (var j = 0; j < captions.length; j++) {
        if (captions[j].begin < p && captions[j].end > p) {
          if (j != caption) {
            var c = document.getElementById('caption' + j);
            if (caption > -1) {
              document.getElementById('caption' + caption).className = "";
            }
            c.className = "current";
            if (query == "") {
              transcript.scrollTop = c.offsetTop - transcript.offsetTop - 40;
            }
            caption = j;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    // Hook up interactivity
    transcript.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (e.target.id.indexOf("caption") == 0) {
        var i = Number(e.target.id.replace("caption", ""));
        playerInstance.seek(captions[i].begin);
      }
    });
    /**/
    
    search.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        search.select();
      }, 100);
      resetSearch();
      $("#prevMatchLink").hide();
      $("#nextMatchLink").hide();
    });
    
    search.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        resetSearch();
        $("#prevMatchLink").hide();
        $("#nextMatchLink").hide();
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#prevMatchLink").show();
        $("#nextMatchLink").show();
        var q = this.value.toLowerCase();
        if (q.length > 0) {
          if (q == query) {
            if (cycle >= matches.length - 1) {
              cycleSearch(0);

            } else {

              cycleSearch(cycle + 1);
            }
          } else {
            resetSearch();
            searchTranscript(q);
          }
        } else {
          resetSearch();
        }
      } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        cycleSearch(cycle - 1);
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        cycleSearch(cycle + 1);
      }
    });

    $("#prevMatchLink").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      cycleSearch(cycle - 1);
    });

    $("#nextMatchLink").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      cycleSearch(cycle + 1);
    });

    // Execute search
    function searchTranscript(q) {
      matches = [];
      query = q;
      for (var i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
        var m = captions[i].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(q);
        if (m > -1) {
          document.getElementById('caption' + i).innerHTML =
            captions[i].text.substr(0, m) + "<em>" +
              captions[i].text.substr(m, q.length) + "</em>" +
              captions[i].text.substr(m + q.length);
          matches.push(i);
        }
      }
      
      if (matches.length) {
        cycleSearch(0);
      } else {
        resetSearch();
      }
    };

    function cycleSearch(i) {
      if (cycle > -1) {
        var o = document.getElementById('caption' + matches[cycle]);
        o.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].className = "";
      }
      var c = document.getElementById('caption' + matches[i]);
      c.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].className = "current";
      match.innerHTML = (i + 1) + " of " + matches.length;
      transcript.scrollTop = c.offsetTop - transcript.offsetTop - 40;
      cycle = i;
    };

    function resetSearch() {
      if (matches.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById('caption' + i).innerHTML = captions[i].text;
        }
      }
      query = "";
      matches = [];
      match.innerHTML = "0 of 0";
      cycle = -1;
      transcript.scrollTop = 0;
    };

    var videoTitle = $(".videoTitle").text();
    var hasPlayed = false;

    playerInstance.onBeforePlay(function (event) {
      if (hasPlayed == false) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'Play', videoTitle);
        hasPlayed = true;
      }
    });

    //Can be used to trigger the Course to Marked Completed so the user doesn't have to
    playerInstance.on('complete', function () {

    });

    function loadChapters() {

      $.get(chapter_file, function (data) {
        data = data.trim();
        var c = data.split("\n\r\n");
        var d;

        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
          d = c[i].split("\n");
          //pushes in Title for each chapter
          toc.push(d[0]);
          //pushes in the time intervals for each chapter
          seekArr.push(d[1]);
        };

        for (var a = 0; a < seekArr.length; a++) {
          //Splits the time interval and pushes the start interval for each chapter
          var tempPos = seekArr[a].split(" --> ");
          seekPos.push(tempPos[0]);
        };

        runTOC(seekPos);
        var toc_output = "";
        $.each(toc, function (i, v) {
          toc_output += "<li class=ch" + i + "><a href='#' onclick='jwplayer().seek(" + toc_seconds(seekPos[i]) + ");'>" + v + "</a> (" + toc_time(seekPos[i]) + ")</li>"
        });

        if (toc.length < 7) {
          toc_output += " <li class='blank'> </li><li class='blank'> </li>";
        }

        $(".courseTitles ul").html(toc_output);
      });
    };

    function runTOC(x) {
      playerInstance.onTime(function (event) {

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (event.position > toc_seconds(x[i])) {
            $(".courseTitles ul li").removeClass("active");
            $(".courseTitles ul li.ch" + i).addClass('active');
          }
        };
      });
    }
  });
});
```

We are hosting the video and Chapter/Captions VTT files using Amazon Web Services with Cloudfront.

We have included the interactive transcript from the captions as well as dynamic video chapters to be loaded once the video is ready to be played.

One thing I have noticed is that the chapters and the transcript do not always load and require the page to be refreshed several times so I was thinking that maybe it was a caching issue on the AWS side of the equation.

I have used Google Chrome and there are no errors in the developers console when the chapters and transcript do not load.

It should be noted that this functionality was working flawlessly when were using the JW Platform cloud hosted solution so it seems to be a factor of the AWS/Cloudfront CDN.

```js
      function load_jwp_scripts() { 
     
   wp_enqueue_script('jwplayer-js', plugins_url( "/js/jwplayer.js", __FILE__), array(), '1.0', false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jwplayer-license-js', plugins_url( "/js/jwplayer_license.js", __FILE__), array(), '1.0', false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jwplayer-player-js', plugins_url( "/js/player.js", __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
   
      }
  
     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jwp_scripts');
```

Comment: Hm, the captions are loading correctly for me here, how often does it fail?

Comment: Hello Ethan  The CC for the player seems to load fine but I have implemented the Interactive Transcript from the Experiments section of JW Platform and it was working fine with the JW Platform hosted player  (http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/jw-player-cloud-hosted) but my local player with AWS Cloudfront does not display them consistently.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - It will fail 8 times out of 10.

Comment: The Transcript always seems to be loading for me on my machine on your self hosted link. Firefox 41, Win7.

Comment: I've looked at in Chrome, IE and Firefox and it does seem to work more consistently in Firefox but I am still having issues where it does not load.

Comment: Hm, I would check the response headers of our platform embed vs yours to see if they match up, maybe there is something different? I don't know enough about AWS to know what that might be though.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - I don't think it is a function of AWS after all.  There appears to be some issue with the embed.  I've noticed that the jwplayer() object does not always fire an onReady event or .on("ready" event.  There are no errors reported but something has to be affecting the way it renders.  Does anything look amiss?

Comment: Have you tried to load a simple console log or alert in the onReady event to see if it fires?

Comment: Yes, I have included a console.log statement on. ("ready") and it does not fire consistently.  I should add that this is being implemented in WordPress bit there is no official support for JW Player 7 in WordPress yet.

Comment: How are you loading the player in then? We don't have an official plugin for WP yet.

Comment: I just added the code from Wordpress that enqueues JWplayer, the License Script and the custom player.js file

Comment: So you just added it to your theme's template, for example?

Comment: It was added as a plugin but following the same logic.

Comment: Update:  It seems to work fine in Firefox, sporadically in Google Chrome and IE Edge.   The times that it does not work the jwplayer().onReady ( function () { console.log("Player is Ready"); }); does not fire either.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to chat but we are looking to hire someone to help polish this UI for us.  IF you are interested I can provide contact info.

Comment: Sorry, I am not available for hire for this. I would try to load the player normally, not via a plugin, just as our documentation says.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - Can you point me in the direction of some developers who have the experience I am looking for?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know of anyone off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workable solution to my problem.

The issue was the use of the $(document).ready declaration.  It is not compatible with jwplayer.on("ready").

Removing that and it is rendering properly again.

Comment: Nice, glad you got it fixed.